# Styling specific characters within a font?

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

Is it possible (perhaps with jquery) to specify a set of characters for styling?

In this particular case, I'm dealing with a client's font that uses numbers which are a shade too small. I could imagine other applications where you want to change the color of font-weight of specific characters, like question marks or exclaimaton points.

Comment: Yes it's possible. The implementation would depend on many factors. Can you show us your HTML and current code?

Comment: [**unicode-range @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-range)

Answer (score 2):

The following code changes all the numbers with span tag, which has a better styling and readability:

```js
$(function () {
  re = /(\d+)/g;
  re.test($("p").html());
  $("p").html($("p").html().replace(re, "<span>$1</span>"));
});
```

```css
p span {color: #00f; font-weight: 700;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem 1 sit 23 ipsum.</p>
```